# Hard circuit problem

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

I want to find the p.d. between points A and B. I'm not sure how to approach this problem though, could I have a hint?

[image]

Comment: Apply kirchhoff's voltage law to the outer circuit (EDCHGFE) and detrmine the voltage difference between F and C. The branch FC is an open circuit, what does that tell you about the voltage between B and C??

Comment: I don't know that law...

Comment: *I don't know that law...* then here's a hint you can take to the bank:  *learn Kirchoff's Circuit Laws now*.

Answer (score 1):

No current flows from C to B or A to F. So if you can find the potentials at C and F, you need only add or subtract the 4V potential. I would start by defining the potential at C, D and H to be zero.
12-8 and 10+5 may help get current for D to H, remember potential from D to H is zero, that's a wire.

Looking forward to your final solution.